# Connect local packages in monorepo with lerna

Tags: typescript, lerna, monorepo

I'm trying to setup a Monorepo with Lerna and yarn workspaces, but the thing that I cannot get to work is where I try to add packages as a dependency of an other local package

So, what does that mean

I have a project structure like this

```
/
 packages/
          a/
            src/a.ts
          b/
            src/b.ts
          ab/
            src/ab.ts
```

Very basic, its for testing only. I've also create a [public repository](https://github.com/scaljeri/lerna) with this structure and all the other files in place. You can follow the readme to reproduce the problem.

So, `a.ts` looks like this

```
export class A {
    get(): string {
        return 'a';
    }
}
```

`b.ts` looks very similar and `ab.ts` uses both as follows

```
import { A } from '@myScope/a';    
import { A } from '@myScope/b';

export class Ab {
    getA(): A {
       return new A();
    }
    getB(): B {
       return new B();
    }
```

Now, when I build these with `lerna run build`, which is nothing more than `tsc` on all three files, I get errors, telling me that the modules imported in `ab.ts` cannot be found. So the question is, how can I add my two local packages?

Comment: You don't have `@myScope/a` and `@myScope/b` in the `dependencies` of `package.json` in `@myScope/ab`, so `lerna bootstrap` does not add them to `node_modules` in `ab` where TypeScript expects them to be

Comment: Thats it @artem,  I needed to do `lerna add ...`. Thanks a lot for pointing that out!